# Проблема с записью в текстовый файл из DataGridView

Tags: c#

Собственно, записывает в файл всё, кроме последней записи в строке DataGridView (получается 5, а должно быть 6).

```cs
if(Квитанция.Checked == true)
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream("Kvitancii.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
                fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(dataGridView1[0, i].Value + "\t" + dataGridView1[1, i].Value + "\t" + dataGridView1[2, i].Value + "\t" + dataGridView1[3, i].Value + "\t" + dataGridView1[4, i].Value + "\t" + dataGridView1[5, i].Value);
                }

                sw.Close();
                fs.Close();
            }
```

Пытаясь прочитать файл, естественно выдаёт ошибку System.IndexOutOfRangeException

```cs
 if(Квитанция.Checked == true)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                string buffer;

                    FileStream fs = new FileStream("Kvitancii.txt", FileMode.Open);
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
                    fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        buffer = sr.ReadLine();
                        string[] words = buffer.Split(new char[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(words[0], words[1], words[2], words[3], words[4], words[5]);
                    }
                    sr.Close();
                    fs.Close();
                }
```

Не могу понять, в чём проблема.

Comment: `.Count - 1` уберите  -1

Comment: @4per Убрал, ошибка осталась.

Comment: debugger вам в помощь

Comment: Наверняка при записи некоторые значения `dataGridView1[..., i].Value` являются пустыми. Поэтому из-за `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` массив получается короче. Уберите этот параметр.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Вы правы, спасибо большое.